# json_encode breaks on image url

Tags: php, json

I have a weird issue with `json_encode`. I have a table that I dump the user submissions in to for backup, but for some reason lately the image url breaks after a certain length. I'm not sure if it is because the photo is too big, but I don't see any fixes for this other than the `JSON_PARTIAL_OUTPUT_ON_ERROR`. Is there any way this can be fixed or some preventative for this?

```js
{"task": [{
  "Hours": "12",
  "Photo": ["data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAASABIAAD/4QBYRXhpZgAATU0AKgAAAAgAAgESAAMAAAABAAEAAIdpAAQAAAABAAAAJgAAAAAAA6ABAAMAAAABAAEAAKACAAQAAAABAAADAKADAAQAAAA //It breaks right here
```

I only put a snippet of the base64 url to save space, but it breaks at the end.

Comment: A [mcve] must include relevant database insertion code, table definitions, etc. In particular if the string length appears to be at issue. Else this is just observational guessing.

Comment: What does `json_last_error` say? https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php

Comment: This `-------------------  //breaks right there`

Comment: @ceejayoz it says no error when it runs, should I not worry about it?

Comment: Does it work for other big images? If you manually remove some of the base64 string, does it submit then?

Comment: I've ran other tests that doesn't break with other images of similar sizes. The issue seems to be sporadic. This data is coming from an app so that may be another variable involved, but just being able to catch this and ensure nothing else breaks is my goal.

Comment: Can you clarify what "break" means? The image doesn't work? The rest of the JSON is missing?

Comment: The rest of the JSON is missing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most likely cause of your problem is that the database column you are inserting this data into has a limited size, and the JSON you are inserting is larger than that limit, so it is being truncated.

Solution is simple: change the database schema to allow longer values.

Comment: Oh, that's an aspect I hadn't considered. Good idea. 

Comment: Thank you so much! This actually was the cause of the issue. In mySQL we had the column value as SMALL TEXT which was only grabing about 64k characters. The picture was actually a big part of that, but the structure of the JSON was causing it to exceed the limit. We cahnged to MEDIUM TEXT and everything started coming in as it should! I appreciate this perspective and feed back.